# Why my Spannable text edit is not getting applied?

Tags: android

I am new to android,
i have a textView and i am doing like this to setText(There is only one text box)

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(message);
        wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),0,message.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        wordtoSpan.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),0,message.length(),0);
        tv.setText(wordtoSpan);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
       // Log.v(TAG, "hi");
        while(line != null) {
            if(message.equals(line)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "hi");
                while(!("end".equals(line))) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "hello");
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    tv.setText(tv.getText() +" \n" + line);
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
```

The Spannable string is not getting applied.
But when i remove second setText then the spannable string is applied 
How android handles the text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setText` is checked if the provided `CharSequence` is an instance of `Spanned`

getText() is returning a CharSequence which might be an instance of `Spanned`.

But if you do `+ " \n" + line` it gets converted to a String, so the stuff you have in `Spannable` will not be applied.

Comment: Thanks i got the point, is there any way other than using two textView  for this scenario ?

Comment: You can use a SpannableStringBuilder. Take a look at the [doku](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#SpannableStringBuilder(java.lang.CharSequence)). If you need any more help with this, please open up a new question.